# Create new variable based on averages of variable in subset of other dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes, of which a simplified representation is given below.

```
df1 <- data.frame("From" = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
                  "To" = c("Z", "Y", "X"))

df2 <- data.frame("Zone" = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"),
                  "Value" = seq(1, 9, 1))
```

I want to create a third dataframe, containing the variables of `df1` and a new variable (for this purpose let's call the new variable `Diff` (in new dataframe `df3`), which is based on the averages of the `df2$Value`, but in a specific way. The new `df3$Diff` variable needs to be the average of `df2$Value` where the `df2$Zone`equals the `df1$From` value, substracted from the average of `df2$Value`where the `df2$Zone` equals the `df1$To` value.
This would yield the following, new dataframe:

```
df3 <- data.frame("From" = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
                  "To" = c("Z", "Y", "X"),
                  "Diff" = c(6, 0, -6))
```

I have tried the following code (and variations on it) but it does not seem to work:

```
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Diff = mean(df2$Value[df2$Zone == df1$`To`], na.rm = TRUE) 
         - mean(df2$Value[df2$Zone == df1$`From`], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the average value for each `Zone` in `df2` and join `df1` with it. Once the `Value` is available you can `match` it with other column (`To` here) to get it's corresponding `Value` to subtract.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>%
  summarise(Value = mean(Value), .by = Zone), join_by(From == Zone)) %>%
  mutate(Diff = Value[match(To, From)] - Value) %>%
  select(-Value)

#  From To Diff
#1    X  Z    6
#2    Y  Y    0
#3    Z  X   -6
```